# How to modify data whilst importing in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have more than 20k form responses (***google sheet*** and google form) where some guys have selected the wrong data which is visible in my responses. How I know its wrong is because they needed to select the activity (an attribute) but they selected the similar activity name (let's call it X) which was for the previous year and this year's activity (let's call it Y) should have been the different one.
I know that after a certain date all the X activities are Y, so I need to modify the data while importing it from the responses.
I tried conditional formatting on the data but then the importrange doesn't work, it needs cells to be empty to work.
I learned about query statements but it doesn't allow UPDATE.
Please help me do this, I am okay if we need to use a macro. I'm looking for something like this (note that the following is the logic I'm looking for and not the actual code):

```
if date>"a date" and FC==X:
  FC=Y
#FC being the column I wanna modify
```

Edit: I am unable to share the table as its confidential. Can tell you that first column is date/time of form and then there are 149 columns, one of them I need to modify based on the date. Let's Assume it has just 2 columns, A: date, B: activity (has 20 activities). So, if they have filled "X" activity after  then change that activity to Y. I hope it helps in understanding.

Edit 2: Have put a [dummy file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pJ0_i-slCCUUfr_tsXWgck1gJUioce4Trj7kQ4LK1Kc/edit?usp=sharing) as asked. So now the problem statement is after 21 May 2022 (inclusive) all "6" activity must be "2"

Comment: Which? Excel or Googlesheets?

Comment: If google sheets, and if the respones come from Google Form, it may be usefull to work with onformsubmit. Share a sample of your spreadsheet.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @MikeSteelson thanks for the response. I have done some changes in the question pls take a look.

Comment: You can always create a sheet of dummy data that people can access and play with. By doing so, people will be more eager to help out.;

Comment: Have put the files

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⇩ M E N U ⇩')
    .addItem(' Update', 'myFunction')
    .addToUi();
}

function myFunction() {
  // parameters
  var param = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Param')
  var from = param.getRange('A2').getValue()
  var before = param.getRange('B2').getValue()
  var after = param.getRange('C2').getValue()

  // data
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var range = sh.getDataRange()
  var data = range.getValues()
  data.filter(r => (r[0] >= from && r[1] == before)).forEach(r => r[1] = after)
  range.setValues(data)
}
```

To avoid hardcoding and potential issue with dates, I put all parameters in a new tab called "Param" as follows

[image]